# Testing containment with HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I am writing a program in Java where I would like to use HashSet (and HashMap). I am having trouble getting the contains (and containsKey) method(s) to work. I guess I have to override some equals method somewhere for this to work. The idea is to get the following piece of code to produce output: true. Any thoughts on how I can do that?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sets {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Set<StringBuilder> wordSet = new HashSet<StringBuilder>();
        StringBuilder element = new StringBuilder("Element");
        wordSet.add(element);
        StringBuilder element2 = new StringBuilder("Element");
        System.out.println(wordSet.contains(element2));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `StringBuilder` here, since `StringBuilder` uses reference equality, not equality of contents.  Just use `String` instead.

(This makes sense, as `StringBuilder` is mutable, and two `StringBuilder`s may be equal at one point and unequal later.  It's not a question of writing a `hashCode()` or `equals` method, since `StringBuilder` isn't a class you wrote, it's built into Java.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the code I want to write, I need to build words iteratively, so I want to use StringBuilder there and need to store the current list of words in a HashSet.

Comment: Once you've built up a `StringBuilder`, just use its `toString()` method to get it back to a `String`.  As long as you only use `String`s in your `HashSet`, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder does not override the default hashCode() and equals() methods, so it uses Object's implementation - which basically does a == check. as youre not using the exact same StringBuilder instance, the contains() call returns false.

as the class is final you cannot extend it to add equals() and hashCode(), so you need to you your own class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a StringBuilder.  Use a string.